# SQL Subquery issue not yielding any error and result

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I am writing a simple select subquery statement and it is not giving any result. Neither it is throwing any error.
My Sql query is like this -

```
select * from Table1
where id in (select ID from Table2 where user = 'xyz')
```

I tried with exists also, but not showing any result.
Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that the below subquery returns a empty list because the filter condition `where user = 'xyz'`  doesn't matches any record

```
select ID from Table2 where user = 'xyz'
```

The outer query as below doesn't matches the condition `where id in ()`

```
select * from Table1 where id in ()
```

Thus returning an empty result set.

You can convert your posted query to be a `INNER JOIN` query like

```
select t1.* 
from Table1 t1 join Table2 t2 
on t1.id = t2.id
where t2.user = 'xyz';
```

As a test, try using `LIKE` operator instead of equality comparison

```
select * from Table1
where id in (select ID from Table2 where user like '%xyz%')
```